# Why IP scanning wouldn't show my computer in the list?

Tags: java, network-programming, ip, scanning

I make a simple program to scan my network IPs and list all available devices:

```
InetAddress localhost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
byte[] ip = localhost.getAddress();
ip[3] = (byte) x;
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip);
if (!address.getHostAddress().equals(address.getHostName())) {
    avilablePcsList.add(address);
    System.out.println(address.getHostName() + "\t" + address.getHostAddress() + "\t" + NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(address));
}
```

but this code get all the devices available on my network except my computer, so Why this code didn't show my computer?and How to show it?

 BTW: x is the for loop's counter variable(1:254)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, if it shows localhost then it does show it though. I mean can't you just use localhost for the host ip if you need to use it somewhere in your code?

From another post

The NetworkInterface class contains all the relevant methods, but be aware that there's no such thing as "my IP". A machine can have multiple interfaces and each interface can have multiple IPs.

You can list them all with this class but which interface and IP you choose from the list depends on what you exactly need to use this IP for.